# Colocar informações em campos field de uma URL e enviar para o servidor com uma linguagem de programa

Tags: java, lua

É possível, usando uma linguagem de programação, acessar uma página de internet com dados de login e senha, setar as informações de login e senha e "clicar" no botão de enviar, podendo entrar no site com suas credenciais?

Depois disto é possível navegar no site coletando informações do source, etc.?

Estou utilizando Lua para testes, mas posso testar com Java também.

A URL que estou tentando utilizar é https://acad.unoesc.edu.br/academico/login.jsp

Em Lua, eu consigo o código fonte e status, etc, com o `luasocket(http)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo HttpURLConnection é uma boa maneia de começar, mas por fins práticos te aconselho a dar uma olhada nesse blog do Vogella:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html

Lá tem exemplo de um POST request para uma login page, usando o Apache HttpClient.

Abraços

Comment: Eu conheço essas funções e também a biblioteca ApatcheHttpClient, já utilizei pra baixar imagens de um site utilizando Java, porém, não consigo "entender" o funcionamento de setar parâmetros, por exemplo, JS, e "enviá-los" ao servidor.

Comment: @rodrigokiller tente dar uma olhada melhor nesse
[Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/)
Isso é Java puro, mas acredito mesmo que neste caso sua real dúvida mesmo seja com protocolo HTTP em sí.
Se puder fornecer mais detalhes da sua dúvida...

Comment: O que você não entendeu exatamente? Você quer fazer um POST para a URL `https://acad.unoesc.edu.br/academico/j_security_check` (o exemplo do Vogella já é um POST) passando os parâmetros `j_username`, `j_password` e `j_uri`, no caso de ApacheHttpClient a passagem de parâmetros é por exemplo `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "fulano"));` como o blog do Vogella exemplifica.

Comment: @JosuéEduardo eu tentei utilizar Postman, por exemplo, na página em questão, setando as keys (j_username e j_password). Porém, não recebi retorno, ou fiz algo errado. De qualquer forma, vocês estão passando diversos materiais, agora é só eu sentar e lê-los. Muito obrigado pelas respostas.

Answer (score 4):

Usando Java você pode usar o framework [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).  Após escrever um script, ele abre o browser e "tem vida própria".

A princípio, selenium é um framework para testes de interface gráfica web, mas nada impede que você use ele pra automatizar tarefas.

No blog do [Dyego Costa](http://dyegocomy.com/blog/primeiros-passos-com-selenium-webdriver/) e tem o seguinte exemplo de como usar o selenium, para ter uma idéia de como é fácil. No exemplo ele faz uma pesquisa no google:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MeuTesteSuperMassaSoQueNao()
{
    // Usando o firefox
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // acessa a página do google
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

    // Vai no campo de busca, escreve "Cheese" e aperta enter          
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
    query.SendKeys("Cheese");
    query.Submit();

    // Configura um timeout
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    // Espera até o título da página tiver cheese, tá pronto (ou o timeout acontencer)
    wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title.ToLower().StartsWith("cheese"); });

    // Essa parte é o teste - pode ignorar, já que tu não quer testar nada
    driver.Title.Should().Contain("cheese");

    // fecha o browser
    driver.Quit();
}
```

Se preferir ruby, o [watir](http://watir.com/) é muito simples e gostoso de usar.

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada nisto, assim que possível dou o feedback.

Comment: @rodrigokiller as ordens

Comment: como estou testando Lua, vou testar http://luaselenium.sourceforge.net/ que parece ser o cliente do Selenium para Lua.

Comment: @rodrigokiller legal, dei uma procurada e não tinha achado :-)

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver no Windows, pode usar o [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) uma ferramenta que eu acho bastante útil. Eu uso normalmente para mexer com o mouse e o teclado, mas ele faz muito além disso.

Abaixo eu peguei um código para entrar na página e se logar.

```
#include <ie.au3>
$oIE = _IECreate ("http://yoursitename.com")
$oForm = _IEFormGetObjByName ($oIE, "form id or name")
$oQuery1 = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($oForm, "uname textfield id or name")
$oQuery2 = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($oForm, "pwd text field id or name")
$uname="Yourusername"
$pwd="yourpassword"
_IEFormElementSetValue ($oQuery1,$uname)
_IEFormElementSetValue ($oQuery2,$pwd)
$oButton=_IEGetObjById($oIE,"")
_IEAction ($oButton, "click")
_IELoadWait($oIE,0)
```

[fonte](http://solubletech.blogspot.com.br/2011/02/use-autoit-v3-to-make-auto-login-script.html)

Comment: darei uma olhada obrigado :)